# How do i specify a new vnet with 2 subnets when creating VM using Azure management Fluent API

Tags: azure-management-api

Using Azure Management Fluent API how do I create a new VNet with 2 subnets and create 2 VMs with each vm is a separate subnet?

```
    var windowsVM = azure.VirtualMachines.Define("myWindowsVM")
        .WithRegion(Region.USWest)
        .WithNewResourceGroup(rgName)
        .WithNewPrimaryNetwork("10.0.0.0/28")
        .WithPrimaryPrivateIPAddressDynamic()
        .WithNewPrimaryPublicIPAddress("mywindowsvmdns")
        .WithPopularWindowsImage(KnownWindowsVirtualMachineImage.WindowsServer2012R2Datacenter)
        .WithAdminUsername("tirekicker")
        .WithAdminPassword(password)
        .WithSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.StandardD3V2)
        .Create();
```